# Преобразование данных из SQL array_agg

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, pandas

У меня есть CSV таблица с колонкой, содержащей строчки такого вида:

```
    {сообщение один, сообщение два, сообщение три}    
    {NULL, NULL, сообщение пятнадцать}
...
```

И я хочу считать ее, чтобы она превратилась в список строк следующего вида:

```
['сообщение один', 'сообщение два', 'сообщение три']
['NULL', 'NULL', 'сообщение пятнадцать']
```

Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Это пример данных для двух строк __одного__ столбца в CSV? Какой разделитель столбцов используется в CSV?

Comment: Да, это пример для двух строк одного столбца. Разделитель обычный, запятая.

Comment: Ну, я так понял, что проще всего регулярки?)

Comment: Если разделитель -запятая, как вы будете парсить остальные столбцы?? Или в CSV файле только один столбец?

Comment: Только один, там парсинг через \n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [355]: df = pd.read_csv("a.csv", sep="~", header=None, names=["text"])

In [356]: df
Out[356]: 
                                             text
0  {сообщение один, сообщение два, сообщение три}
1              {NULL, NULL, сообщение пятнадцать}

In [357]: df["res"] = df["text"].str.replace(r"[{}]", "").str.split(",\s*")

In [358]: df.loc[0, "res"]
Out[358]: ['сообщение один', 'сообщение два', 'сообщение три']

In [359]: df.loc[1, "res"]
Out[359]: ['NULL', 'NULL', 'сообщение пятнадцать']

In [360]: df
Out[360]: 
                                             text                                             res
0  {сообщение один, сообщение два, сообщение три}  [сообщение один, сообщение два, сообщение три]
1              {NULL, NULL, сообщение пятнадцать}              [NULL, NULL, сообщение пятнадцать]
```

Comment: Как всегда -- великолепно :)